# Two optional variables in Symfony2 routing

Tags: symfony, routes

When I try to use 2 optional variables in Symfony2 routing I have th error: No route found for "GET /" 
In routing.yml I have:

```
AcmeAshavatBundle_homepage:
pattern:  /{page}/{ads_on_page}/
defaults: { _controller: AcmeAshavatBundle:Page:index, page:1, ads_on_page:2 }
requirements:
   _method:  GET|POST
```

And when i go to `http://localhost:8080/AshavatSy/web/app_dev.php/` I have the error. The intresting is that if I run `http://localhost:8080/AshavatSy/web/app_dev.php/1` it works well.Also, if I change the path to pattern: /main/{page}/{ads_on_page}/ it works well. 

What is the problem?
I'd like to ask, that someone will try to do like this [e.g. pattern: /a/b/ defaults: {... a:1,b:2}, or as he thinks you should do it] in his project, and see is it a common problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to pass these two arguments to your IndexAction() in controller.

Try this code

```
Public function indexAction($page,$ads_on_page)
{}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: initialize the variables with default values in arguments of the action,then try it.indexAction($page=1,$ads_on_page=2)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but it doesn't help. The error is on the routing step. So the system does not reach the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to have something similar working by defining two routes, pointing to the same controller, using default parameters. In my case, using annotations:

```
/**
 * @Route("/products/{catId}/{prodId}", defaults={"catId"="", "prodId"=""})
 * @Route("/products/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($catId = null, $prodId = null) {
    ...
```

I think that  using default parameters only, Symfony would expect two /.

HTH